# is this a proper completion handler?

Tags: swift, closures, swift5, completionhandler

I had a very slow bottom sheet, showing up blank then after a while loading data. I tried to apply a completionHandler `isLoadedCompletionHandler`, solution worked, but my colleague told me this is not a "completion handler". Could you explain me why this is working. And how? Is this a proper completion handler?

```
func buttonDetailTapped(with travelSolutionId: String) {
           guard let currentPurchaseSolution = purchaseSolutions.value.first(where: { $0.xmlId == purchaselSolutionId }) else {return}

           getAllPurchaseDetail(searchId: searchId.value, solutionId: purchaseSolutionId)
               .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] purchaseDetails in
                   let isLoadedCompletionHandler: ([PurchaseDetail]) -> Void = { theArray in
                       self?.result.onNext(.showPurhcaseSolutionDetails(purchaseDetails, currentTravelSolution))
                   }
                   isLoadedCompletionHandler(purchaseDetails)
               })
               .disposed(by: disposeBag)
       }
```

Comment: The currently shown code is the code after you "tried to apply a completionHandler", right? Can you show the code before you "tried to apply a completionHandler"?

Answer (score 0):

A completion handler is a function that you pass into your function, which usually gets called upon the completion of some asynchronous task.

Your function of `buttonDetailTapped` contains no parameters that are functions (i.e. `(Thing, Error) -> Void`) which are called *upon completion*, and thus you cannot know from calling this function *when it completes*.

Your function may go ahead and do other things when it's done, but there is no completion handler.

Comment: How would you implemented it

Comment: There are a lot of great resources for learning Swift from scratch online! SO is a wonderful place to get insight into a lot of questions, but what you're asking is too broad. Check out this link for more info, including complete implementation details: https://grokswift.com/completion-handler-faqs/

Answer (score 0):

`isLoadedCompletionHandler` is not a completion handler because it is called immediately after it is assigned.

A completion handler is a closure that you pass into a function, that will be called when whatever that function is doing asynchronously completes. You are not passing `isLoadedCompletionHandler` anywhere.

You could have just written

```
getAllPurchaseDetail(searchId: searchId.value, solutionId: purchaseSolutionId)
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] purchaseDetails in
        self?.result.onNext(.showPurhcaseSolutionDetails(purchaseDetails, currentTravelSolution))
   })
   .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

and achieved the same result.